# Get user time line all tweets in iOS 4

Tags: ios, twitter, latitude-longitude

I want to get all tweets of user time line in iOS 4 with time, username, user image and user location latitude and longitude and post tweets on particular user wall with user current location latitude and longitude. How can I perform this?

Please provide me detailed information/link/url by which i can get all fields (i.e. username, time etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two different questions. First, you want to look at the Twitter developers api to retrieve the data in a json format. Then, you want to find out how to parse the json data in iOS and display it.

You can read up on the Twitter API here: [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/).

Also, any reason for using iOS 4? The majority of users are now on iOS 5 or 6.